# Error importing hdfs data into hbase by pig

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

The version of my cluster is {hadoop2.7.1,hbase1.1.2,pig0.15}
i tried importing hdfs data into hbase by pig but i found problems, the error logs shows like this:

---

```
ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse:
<file 3hbase.pig, line 4, column 4> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments '[gprsinfo:Direction gprsinfo:Latitude gprsinfo:Longitude gprsinfo:Returntime gprsinfo:Speed gprsinfo:Id]'

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Pig script failed to parse:
<file 3hbase.pig, line 4, column 4> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments '[gprsinfo:Direction gprsinfo:Latitude gprsinfo:Longitude gprsinfo:Returntime gprsinfo:Speed gprsinfo:Id]'
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1748)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.access$000(PigServer.java:1443)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.parseAndBuild(PigServer.java:387)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:412)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:398)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:171)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:234)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:631)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:177)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse:
<file 3hbase.pig, line 4, column 4> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments '[gprsinfo:Direction gprsinfo:Latitude gprsinfo:Longitude gprsinfo:Returntime gprsinfo:Speed gprsinfo:Id]'
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:199)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1735)
        ... 16 more
Caused by:
<file 3hbase.pig, line 4, column 4> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments '[gprsinfo:Direction gprsinfo:Latitude gprsinfo:Longitude gprsinfo:Returntime gprsinfo:Speed gprsinfo:Id]'
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildStoreOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1009)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.store_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:7806)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1669)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1102)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:560)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:191)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments '[gprsinfo:Direction gprsinfo:Latitude gprsinfo:Longitude gprsinfo:Returntime gprsinfo:Speed gprsinfo:Id]'
        at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:772)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildStoreOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:988)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:740)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.setCacheBlocks(Z)V
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage.initScan(HBaseStorage.java:427)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage.<init>(HBaseStorage.java:368)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage.<init>(HBaseStorage.java:239)
        ... 29 more
```

Comment: It says `Scan.setCacheBlocks() method not found`, But it method is there. For others, link to source :https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/1.1.2/hbase-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.java

Comment: What does your pig script look like? It seems you are trying to pass some data into the HBaseStorage function that it is initially complaining about

Answer (score 0):

Pig only includes HBase connectors for HBase versions < 1.0 (check Pig's lib dir for your specific Pig version) to keep hadoop1 compatibility.

You have to either downgrade to that version of HBase or recompile Pig from source against HBase 1.1.2.

edit: discussed in more detail here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4728

Answer (score 0):

You can go for other version and this integration is working for me.

Hadoop 2.5.2, 
hbase 0.98
 pig 0.15

I hope your problem will be resolve